# Why no overflow when byte exceeds size?

Tags: java, size, overflow, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't Java Number datatypes overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536864/why-dont-java-number-datatypes-overflow)

In Java, when keeping on incrementing a `Byte` value and when it exceeds the size capacity, why is it not throwing any runtime exception ? For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b = 127;
    ++b;
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

The above code will print `-128`. Will it not be better if it throws `RuntimeException`? Why is it designed this way?

Same case for other primitive types too, for `Integer`:

```
int c = 2147483647;
++c;
System.out.println(c);
```

The above code prints `-2147483648`.

Answer (score 7):

Integer overflow is actually quite useful in computing.  If it threw exceptions, lots of clever algorithms would suddenly break or become impractical.  For example, anything involving fixed-point arithmetic would suddenly be plagued with exceptions.

The thing is, overflow is not normally a problem because we put limits into our programs to prevent it from happening (if it would lead to problems).  Other times, we design programs to specifically exploit it.

Don't think of overflow as "a value exceeding its maximum size".  That is not technically possible.  The bits simply wrap around and stay within that data type's limits.

If you need to check for overflow and want to generate exceptions, you can do this:

```
byte b = 127;
byte oldb = b;
b++;
if( b < oldb ) {
    // Calamity!!!  Raise an exception!
}
```

Do not fear your integer limits.  Learn to understand and work with them.

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the [JVM Specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iadd): *"Despite the fact that overflow may occur, execution of an iadd instruction never throws a runtime exception."*

Answer (score 1):

The way integer and floating point arithmetic works is based on how the same operations work in C which is based on how CPUs generally work. An overflow or underflow doesn't trigger an exception (other there are flags which unfortunately java cannot access) There is only one operation which triggers an exception and that is integer divide by zero which triggers a processor interrupt on many types of cpus.  Floating point division by zero is defined as Not-A-Number so this doesn't trigger an interrupt.

Comment: In a 32-bit machine, for doing 64-bit arithmetic the complier must have the intelligence to combine two 32-bit (2 bytes). In this case will it not need to have the knowledge of overflow occurring ?

Comment: A 32-bit processor has add, subtract, multiply and compare operations which can be combined to make any length of bits. Division is more complicated but it can be done with a loop.